# Database files and ASP.NET Login controls

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, security, authentication

I was trying the ASP.NET login control tutorial and everything works well. However, I do not know how to have the Log-in control use my own database (SQL Server 2005) instead of using it's mdf file. I also have no idea where this file was created from since it doesn't show up at all on my solution. Any literature that I can find on the workings of the Login control would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you use ASP.NET's Membership features, you need to specify a provider. In the machine.config file (which lives in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\CONFIG) a default provider is specified that uses a local .mdf file in the app_data folder. Since you don't want that, you can override it in your app's web.config file like so:

```
<system.web>
  <membership defaultProvider="myMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
      <clear /> <!-- remove the default provider since we're not using it anymore -->
      <add type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
           name="myMembershipProvider"
           connectionStringName="myConnectionString"
           applicationName="MyApplicationName" />
    </providers>
  </membership>
</system.web>
```

If you're using other features like roles, personalization, or profiles, you'll need to define providers for them as well in a similar way.

Now you need to actually create the database/tables on your server. To do this, use C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\[version]\aspnet_regsql.exe. The connection string for your provider should point to the database that this utility will create for you.

Answer (score 1):

A few excellent references for asp.net login controls:

[Sitepoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/asp-net-2-security/)

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178329.aspx)

And [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/learn/security/)