# Visual Studio login control produces A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, login-control

I have been troubleshooting this issue for 5 days, so I think I may need some help.

In Visual Studio, I create a new project, select ASP.NET Web Application, and select the Empty template. I am able to drag a GridView object onto a page, select a SQL Server data source, and complete the setup of the GridView object.  When I view the page in a browser, the DataGrid is displaying the data from SQL Server. This verifies that I am able to connect to SQL Server and display data.

[image]

I am able to drag a Login control onto a page. I set the authentication mode to Forms in the web.config file.

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Forms" />
</system.web>
```

I press Ctrl F5 to view the page in a browser. The Login object is displayed. When I enter a username and password and click the Login button, the page loads for about 1 minute, and then produces this error: *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).*

I am using the machine that has Visual Studio, IIS and SQL Server Express installed, which should eliminate things such as remote connectivity. The problem persists if I disable Windows firewall. I do not have any additional hardware or software firewalls at play here.

Researching this using the book *Beginning ASP.NET 4* by Imar Spaanjaars, Imar states that the Login control talks to the ASP.NET application service providers, which is a software layer that sits between the login control and the SQL Server database. The very first time you try to log in, the application service providers check to see if your application is using a database with the necessary database objects, such as the appropriate tables and roles. If not, the application service providers automatically creates the ASPNETDB.MDF. When I select the Login button, the ASPNETDB.MDF file is not automatically created.

[image]

One thing that caught my eye is that Imar Spaanjaars book states that the “*application services providers sits between the login controls and SQL Server database*.” However, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318475/database-files-and-asp-net-login-controls) post on StackOverflow talks about having the login control use SQL Server **instead** of the MDF file. I am a little confused. I am not sure if there is some difference between and MDF file and SQL Server.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050262/creating-mdf-with-sql-2008-express-visual-web-developer-2008) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13074273/unable-to-auto-create-aspnetdb-mdf-visual-web-developer-express-2008-sql-exp/13096096#13096096) article on StackOverflow state to ensure that Visual Studio is pointing to the correct instance of SQL Server. When I connect to SQL Server Express using SQL Server Management Studio, my Server name is WIMA1\WIMA1. In Visual Studio, I select **Tools** > **Options**, then select **Database Tools** > **Data Connections**, and I set the instance name to WIMA1\WIMA1.

[image]

[This](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/05/13/sql-network-interfaces-error-26-error-locating-serverinstance-specified/) Microsoft Blog does a great job at explaining why this error appears. This article mentions that this error should only appear if you are using a named instance of SQL Server, which I am (WIMA1\WIMA1).

Some articles on StackOverflow mention that the connection to SQL Server must be done using SQL Server Authentication instead of Windows Authentication. Using SQL Server Management Studio, I am able to connect to SQL Server with both SQL Server Authentication and Windows Authentication. In Visual Studio, I add database1.mdf to the App_Data folder. I right-click the database1.mdf file and select **Modify Connection**. In the Modify Connection dialog box, if the Data source is Microsoft SQL Server Database File (SqlClient), the Test Connection is successful when using Windows Authentication. However, when using SQL Server Authentication, the following error appears: *A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).*

If I change the Data source to Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient), I am able to successfully connect using both Windows Authentication and SQL Server Authentication.

[image]

I guess at this point I am in search of any thoughts or tips or suggestions that might help me to better understand what I can try to do next to resolve this so that I can use the Login control.

Comment: How are you validating your username/password  against AD or stored in database ? Did you specify membership provider in config file ?

Comment: @Hakunamatata - Thank you very much for sharing the idea's! Your idea's helped me get past the error. I was able to find a page that had example's to add the membership code to the web.config file. When attempting to sign in, I no longer get the network-instance error, the page returns a response almost instantly with a new error: Could not find stored procedure ‘dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion.’  I was then able to follow an article on StackOverflow, and now I am no longer getting any errors. Thank you so much for helping to lead me down the right path here! :)